# Чи вживається двоїна в сучасному мовленні?

Tags: іменники, число

З усіх особливостей української мови я ніколи в житті не чув, щоб хтось використовував двоїну, на кшталт «Йде дві дівчині», «Було дві годині дня», 
«Дві слові про наукове татарське письменство».

Відповідно, і в письмових текстах вона теж завжди видавалася мені незрозумілою і дивною.

Чи існує двоїна взагалі в сучасному мовленні (передусім усному), чи вона цілковито відмерла? Якщо існує, то можливо існують якісь аудіозаписи, де можна було б почути як вживають/вживали двоїну носії мови?

Comment: Можу сказати, що ще принаймні в 80-х—90-х на Черкащині можна було почути конструкції назразок «три літрі» чи «дві відрі». Попри загальноприйняте твердження, ніби двоїна активно функціонує в діалектах лише деся аж на Волині чи західніше.

Comment: У мене і тато так каже, і баба по маминій лінії теж каже: дві відрі, дві штані. Тобто ця штука ще жива. Тато з Поділля, мамина мама з Київщини.

Answer (score 31):

**З офіційного вжитку двоїну було вилучено** під час [реформи правопису 1933 року](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1933_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83). Тому надмірне її використання може бути сприйнято як архаїзм¹.

Менше з тим, існує доволі велика кількість *нерегулярних* рештків двоїни, які  використовуються у повсякденному вжитку.

Окрім того, деякі діалекти української зберегли вживання двоїни — як у письмовій, так і в усній мові.

---

Типові приклади вживання двоїни у сучасній українській:

1. числівники: *двісті* (порівняйте з *п'ятсот*, *шістсот* тощо)
2. наголос²: *два бра́ти* (порівняйте з *усі брати́*), *дві пі́сні* (*усі пісні́*)
3. чергування голосної: *два си́на* (*усі сини́*)
4. іменники **Жін. та Срд. роду в Наз. та Знх. відмінках** дістають закінчення `-і`: *дві стіні́* (а не *стіни́*)

   1. Правопис³ 1928 року передбачав, що якщо корінь закінчується на `г/к/х`, то вона змінюється на `з/ц/с`: *дві руці́*, *дві нозі́*
5. **парні іменники в Орд. відмінку**: *очима* (проста множина *очами*)
6. власні іменники (прізвища), які означають **сімейство або подружжя**: *там живуть Петренки́*

---

## Зауваження

**(1)** Очевидно, можна рекомендувати користуватися двоїною у художній літературі і поезії, але уникати її у технічних дописах.

**(2)** Історично, праслов'янська мова мала окремі форми для:

- (1) однини
- (2) двох об'єктів
- (3/4) для трьох/чотирьох ([паукальне число](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE))
- (5+) множина

В українській мові форма «2» розповсюдилася на форму «3/4», і тому іноді буває важко відрізнити одну форму від іншої.

**(3)** Останнім за часом словником, який визначав офіційний статус двоїни, є [Харківський правопис Скрипника](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) (1928).

Answer (score 17):

Так, двоїна ще існує, так у письмі як і в усному, але тільки на деякі, рідкі слова.

Хіба найкращий приклад є у Святі Літургії:

> **Двері, двері**! В премудрості будьмо уважні.

Двері переважно подвійні в цьому значінні. Теж буває **плечі** i **очі**.

[Читання, ст. 171-172](http://liber.onu.edu.ua/pdf/zap_rgf_26_2011.pdf):

> Численні праці О. Ф. Жолобова присвячені якраз дослідженню двоїни на 
>   матеріалі старослов’янської мови, де це явище зберігалося найдовше – до ХІІІ 
>   – ХІV ст. [4, 95] (а в старопольській до ХVІ – ХVІІ ст. [4, 8]). В українській 
>   мові двоїна збереглася навіть до ХХ ст. (напр. *дві   руці́,    дві   нозі́,    дві   книзі, 
>   дві   рибі,    дві   дорозі, 
>   дві   слові,     дві   вікні́,    два   рукава*
>    і т. д.) і була вилучена як 
>   застаріла правописною реформою 1933 року [15]
>
> [...]
>
> Прикладом цього твердження можемо навести у першу чергу бога Януса (лат. 
>   Ianus < лат. ianua ‘двері’) (≈ ІІІ ст. до н. е.) – одного з найдавніших 
>   римських богів. Спочатку Янус був богом світла і сонця; вранці він відчиняв 
>   небесну браму й випускав на землю день, а ввечері зачиняв браму. Згодом 
>   став богом входів і виходів. Під опікою Януса були входи і виходи кожного 
>   будинку та міста, тому його зображували з ключем у руках. Зображення бога 
>   з подвійним обличчям ставилися на арках, над дверима і брамами.

Comment: А в селі на Хмельниччині, де жив мій дідусь, говорили старосослов'янською _вдвізі́_ замість _вдвох_:"Йдемо на охоту (полювання) _вдвізі_".

Comment: а чи штані - двоїна?

Comment: @Chizh Так, бо їхня однина не існує; але тепер частіше вживають множину: "штани".

Comment: так, в мене під цим впливом наголос на і виходить часто

Answer (score 9):

"Дві відрі" - то був буденний вираз для моєї бабусі з Вінниччини. Вона, на жаль, вже померла. Цей приклад не можна назвати дуже сучасним, проте...

Comment: Так, у себе в селі на Хмельниччині я теж час від часу чую як: _"дві відрі, дві нозі, дві руці"_. Частіше кажуть _"два теляті"_ ніж _"двоє телят"_ тощо.

Comment: Так, в різних селах Хмельниччини чув в такій форми ці вирази.

Comment: Я з Хмельниччини і підтверджую, що у нас так кажуть.

Answer (score 6):

Приклади з літератури:

- В українській версії роману "Гаррі Поттер і в'язень Азкабану" (перекладач [Відомо-Хто](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%84%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)):

  > — Здається, що так, — недбало відповів Рон. — Але я рвуся туди за
  >   іншим: хочу нарешті потрапити в "Медові **руці**"!
- В Оксани Забужко:

  > "...з отерпом у пучках і сльозами в **очу**».

Наразі двоїною активно послуговуються в діалектах, зокрема північних і південно-західних. Ось щось типу доказу:

[image: Ось щось типу доказу]

Comment: Є підозра, що оголошення просто містить помилку. Чи хазяйка, дійсно, «с»дає саме **дві кімнаті**?

Comment: @bytebuster Тому я й називаю це "чимось типу доказу", а не доказом. Світлина з Закарпаття, а для південно-західного наріччя досі актуальна форма двоїни. А правопис префіксів - досить поширена помилка, але qui sait...

Comment: Не зустрічав такої форми для саме слова "кімната". І якось незвична вона і не звучить.

Comment: Щодо цитати з перекладу "Гаррі Поттера і т. д.": можливо, "руці" -- це множина від "руця" (як зменшувально-пестливе від "рука"; хоча [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/rucja) дає тільки суперечливий приклад із вживанням чи то в множині, чи то в двоїні)?

Answer (score 3):

По всіх Карпатах говорять: "Іти д'хаті" в значенні "додому", "дохати". Дивно, що в Українській мові одне пишеться разом (зазвичай), а інше тільки окремо, хоча вони й близькі за змістом. Суть в тому, не знаю чи дійсно це для всієї території України, словом хата позначають кімнату, покій - тож можливо, що словосполучення "д'хаті" сформувалося під впливом двоїни.... Вжиток цього словосполучення не є архаїзмом, а щоденною нормою спілкування. 
Щодо суті розмови: руці, нозі, штані, штанці, рукавиці, ногавиці.... насправді двоїн досить багато в українській мові, просто люди не завжди розуміють, що вони її вживають. А ще друзі (мало б бути други) ;)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, завжди додавайте до відповідей посилання на поважні джерела, інакше ваші дописи лише запрошуватимуть до заперечень. Наприклад, легко заперечити про «дʼхаті», бо *більшість людей мали одну хату, а не дві*; звідки тоді двоїна? Або можна стверджувати, що «дʼхаті» — це не двоїна, а рештки локативу, так само як *«він знаходиться домів»* або *«в саду»* (не *«в саді»*).

Comment: Те саме стосується тверджень, що щось «є щоденною нормою спілкування»: або воно є нормою і згадується у підручниках, на які треба надати посилання, або воно не є нормою, і тоді відповідь невірна.

Comment: Не все і не завжди можна знайти у підручниках, особливо що стосується двоїни в українській мові. Але автор питався про сучасне мовлення (не мову) і приклад д'хаті я навів із власного досвіду спілкування. Звичайно ж я не збираюся на цю тему писати підручник....

Comment: Так, не все можна знайти. Але дане конкретне запитання не містить ніяких рідкісних явищ, для яких можна робити винятки і дозволяти ненаукові відповіді. Озирніться навколо по нашому сайту; у нас є багато складних запитань, які отримали хороші, якісні, науково-обґрунтовані відповіді. Саме цим наш сайт відрізняється від численних форумів. Упевнений, що і ви також зможете надавати хороші відповіді; просто треба брати за взірець хороші зразки (і не брати поганих).

Comment: Щодо д'хаті - не знаю, до чого тут двоїна. Навряд чи йдеться тут про дві хати.

А от щодо інших прикладів - дякую, це дуже цікаво, про "друзі", "штані" я навіть думав!

Comment: Додам ще приклад пісенний: 
Сміло, други, не теряйте
духа на страшную прю.
Рідну (В)країну спасайте
честь і свободу свою!

Сли ж нам умерти прийдеться.....

Автор слів чи музики скоріш за все невідомий, Хоча є обробка Людкевича... може й інших. Суть в тому, що тут вжито саме множину до слова "друг", а не двоїну...........   (порівняйте, між іншим, "сли", яке використане у цій пісні із російським "если".)

Answer (score 2):

Вживається іще й як! Те, що двоїна "фішка" західних регіонів — це міт.

Полтавщина 2019 рік. Був кілька (5) днів у селі Вісичі (Полт. район) цього року — двоїна зустрічається чи не в кожного третього. Напр., до непристойности, далебі, часто казали слово "руці" (проте відокремлюючи його від мн. "руки") — *взяла у руці по відру й пішла*, проте та сама людина казала і *і звідки йто у наших депутатів руки ростуть!?* (себто, тільки зараз я це утямив, *руки* — це щось **загальне, абстрактне**, про багато людей; а *руці* — це типу як щось одне цільне, як "орган" по типу очі, легені. Коли ми говоримо *легені* ми часто говоримо про один конкретний нероздільний предмет, який складається із двох симетрично розташованих частин).

Потім ще точно пам'ятаю слова: відрі, лапі (одн. лапа), вікні, колІні (!а не колІна). Орудний ще відмінок був: (окрім відомого "очима") граблИма (від граблІ) — *граблИма працюй!*.

Я відчуваю, що ми **сильно** недооцінюємо стереотип *"двоїна" є здебільшого лиш у західних діалектах*... У містах може й немає, але село... Вважаю, що двоїна без підтримки зі сторони держави/філології протримається ще років 60-80, а потім остаточно зникне...

P.S.: як же я жалкую, що був не зробив звукозаписи...