# Як правильно вживати/наголошувати слово "тато" в множині та різних відмінках?

Tags: відмінювання, наголос, declension, число

У живій розмовній практиці рідко вживається множина від іменника `тато`, проте "рідко" не означає "ніколи".

Перше питання - як правильно ставити наголос - `тата́` чи `та́та`, наприклад, в такому реченні:

> Щасливі **тата** і мами миттю хапаються за камери, закидаючи пізніше в
>   мережу сотні фотографій улюбленого чада.

Також допоможіть розібратись, в яких випадках потрібно вживати `татів`, `тат`, `тата`, `тати` і інші похідні.

Comment: *татусі́*, *татусі́в*, *татуся́м*… :-)

Comment: [Це протиріччя](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine38-27.pdf) все ускладнює. У довіднику «Українська літературна вимова і наголос» наз. відм. мн. дається `тáта`, род. відм. мн. `тат`, а от [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/тато) дає відповідно `тáти` та `тат`.

Comment: A «Словник труднощів української мови» (1989, Єрмоленко С.Я.) [дає](http://chernobay.ucoz.com/load/slovniki/slovnik_trudnoshhiv_ukrajinskoji_movi/3-1-0-22) `тати́`, `татíв`, стор 285...

Comment: @YellowSky, я там прокоментував під відповіддю із припущенням стосовно наголосу у `тати́`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Згідно з чинним правописом, правильно відмінювати слово "тато" в множині так:
н. та́ти
р. та́тів (тат)
д. та́там
зн. та́тів (тат)
ор. та́тами
м. на/у та́тах
кл. та́ти

Оскільки в словниках є протиріччя, варто скористатися правописом і з'ясувати все самостійно.

Згідно з [правописом](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par44), слово "тато" належить до II відміни ("(а) іменники чол. роду з кінцевим приголосним основи та із закінченням -о в наз. відмінку (переважно назви осіб)"), твердої групи (чоловічий рід)

**Називний відмінок**

Далі, у [§ 54](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par54) читаємо, що у II відміні, множині, цитую:

> Закінчення -и мають усі іменники чол. роду твердої групи: ...та́ти...

Тобто в правописі окремо вказано написання й наголос слова "тато" у множині в називному відмінку.

**Родовий відмінок**

У [§ 55](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par55) бачимо, що:

> 1. Закінчення -ів (після голосного та апострофа -їв) мають іменники чол. роду та... Примітка. Деякі іменники чол. роду мають і нульове закінчення (основу): ... та́тів (тат)

**Давальний відмінок** ([§ 56](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par56)):

> У давальному відмінку множини другої відміни іменники чол. та середн. роду мають закінчення -ам (у твердій і мішаній групах)

Відповідно, "татам".

**Знахідний відмінок** ([§ 57](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par57)):

> 1. Іменники, що означають істоти, мають закінчення, однакове з родовим відмінком множини

Відповідно, "та́тів"

Решту таблиці можна записати, прочитавши параграфи §58 - §60

Хоч наголоси дани не для всіх відмінків, але дани для називного, родового, знахідного й кличного. У цих відмінках наголос не змінюється (залишається на першому "а"). Відповідно, логічно припустити, що й у решті відмінків він залишається на першому "а".

Comment: +1 Чудово! Тільки ж залишається питання, чому сучасні словники навіть 2000-х років дають наголос на закінченні, `тати́`, `татíв`, що не узгоджується з нормами чинного Правопису...

Comment: А ось на це питання я, на жаль, відповіді не знаю :)

Comment: @YellowSky Хоча невеличке дослідження показує, що проект правопису 2003го року слова "та́ти" ще в прикладах не наводить (http://litopys.org.ua/pdf/proekt_2003.pdf), а 2007го (http://www.dis.kiev.ua/data/Pravopys_2007.pdf) вже наводить. Таким чином, цілком можливо, що саме через велику кількість варіантів відмінювання й наголошування цього слова, його й додали до прикладів у правописі. Так сприймати світ трохи оптимістичніше :)

Comment: @YellowSky, я знаю, чому словники іноді дають наголос `тати́`. Це — рештки **двоїни**, [ось тут](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/31/) детальніше. Тобто, походження може бути або (1) таким само, як у слові `Петренки́` у значенні «пара», або навпаки, (2) спробою боротися з двоїною `та́ти` на користь простої множини `тати́`.