# Чому іноді кажуть "штані"

Tags: відмінювання, іменники

Знаю, що треба казати *штани*, але іноді в розмові чую *штані*, зазвичай з наголосом на останній склад. Наприклад, [ось тут](http://hpclub.com.ua/index.php?showtopic=11216&mode=threaded) можна зустріти

> Наклав у штані від страху!

Чому люди так кажуть? У чім різниця?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Тому що це — **двоїна**.

Більше подробиць — у цьому запитанні і відповідях до нього:
[Чи вживається двоїна в сучасному мовленні?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/31/8)