# Де знаходиться наголос у слові «чоловік»?

Tags: наголос

Я бачив у словнику що наголос завжди на першій літері «і» але часто чую наприклад «чоловікИ» та «чоловікІв». Як насправді правильно?

Comment: «чоловікИ» - це Окличний відмінок множини

Answer (score 6):

Мені здається, тут фігурують два різні явища.

1. Наголос є рудиментом [двоїни](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/44/8). Порівняйте:

   > *два чолов**і́**ки*,
   > *усі чоловік**и́***.

   [Чи вживається двоїна в сучасному мовленні?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/31/)
2. Різниця між формами *чоловік* проти *чоловіків* — для різних значень слова.

   > Примітка. Деякі іменники чол. роду мають і нульове закінчення (основу): ватів (ват), кіловатів (кіловат), татів (тат), чобіт, а також після числівників: сім днів (і день), сто раз (і разів), але днів сім, разів сто; сім **чоловік**, тобто «сім осіб», але сім **чоловіків** — «сім осіб чоловічої статі», **чоловік** із двісті, а також ті іменники, що втрачають у множині суфікси -ин, -їн: болгар, громадян, селян, татар; але: грузинів, осетинів. — [Словник.ua](https://slovnyk.ua/pravopys.php?prav_par=55&prav_swrd=8573#par55p1prym)

Answer (score 1):

Наголос називного відмінка необов'язково зберігається в інших відмінках.

Щодо форм конкретно слова *чоловік*, то різні матеріали чомусь подають різні наголоси:

- Деякі, зокрема «Російсько-український словник» Кримського та Єфремова, «Українська літературна вимова і наголос» (Жовтобрюх М. А., 1973, «Наукова думка»), «Культура мови на щодень» (під. ред. С. Я. Єрмоленко, 2000, «Довіра»), подають основний наголос *чоловік**и́***, *чоловік**і́**в* (але *два чолов**і́**ки*).
- Деякі, зокрема «Словник наголосів української літературної мови» (М. І. Погрібний, 1959, «Радянська школа»), подають паралельні наголоси без уточнення значень: *чолов**і́**ки* й *чоловік**и́***, *чолов**і́**ків* і *чоловік**і́**в*.
- Деякі, зокрема «Словники України online» від УМІФ (але чи не помилка там?), подають наголос *чолов**і́**ки*, *чолов**і́**ків* у всіх значеннях.