# "Речами" чи "речима"? Як відмінювати?

Tags: відмінювання, морфологія

Як все-таки правильно в орудному відмінку? У словниках (kyiv dictionary, горох) стоїть "речами". [На форумі](https://forum.lvivport.com/threads/kultura-slova-movnostilistichni-poradi.29942/page-51) натрапила на нічим не підкріплене правило про парні і непарні речі. Так само цікавить, чому "плечі" в орудному відмінку збереглися як "плечима".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Йдеться, дійсно, про залишки **двоїни**.

У [відповіді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/44/8) на запитання [Чи вживається двоїна в сучасному мовленні?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/31/8) згадується:

> Типові приклади вживання двоїни у сучасній українській:
>
> […]
>
> 5. **парні іменники в Орд. відмінку**: *очима* (проста множина *очами*)

Слушним є уточнення: хоча *речі* не є природно-парним предметом як-то *очі*, *плечі*, часто у практичному мовленні йдеться про "лише декілька речей" (але не всі), отже, форма двоїни може розповсюджуватися на *паукальне число* (декілька речей).

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>Авторка запитання</sub>
>
> Як все-таки правильно в орудному відмінку?

Слово *рїч* входить в третю відміну, бо жїночого роду на шипячий приголосний, гісторично на *-ĭ*.

> <sub>[Правопис 2019](//files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=129) → Ⅱ. Правопис відмінюваних закінчення → Іменник → Ⅲ відміна</sub>
>
> #### § 96. Множина
>
> 4. В орудному відмінку множини вживаємо закінчення **-ями** (після шиплячого — **-ами**): *ві́дповід**ями***, *вíст**я́ми***, *гера́н**ями***, *кост**я́ми*** (рідко *кіст**ьми́***), *о́с**ями***; *ноч**а́ми***, *по́дорож**ами***, *со́міш**ами***.

Тому **речами**, тобто згадані вами словники вказали правильно. Правило зміни *і* на *е* опущено, бо це гинша тема.

Цїкаво, що тут згадано *кістьми*, але то такий [орудний](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F) множини для іменників на основи *-r*, *-ĭ*: [давнеруська] *дьньми*, *каменьми*, *матерьми*, *гостьми* ітд. Таке, справдї, досї вживано як парабіжна форма, втч. в словниках: [*ворітьми*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0), [*гістьми*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C), [*грудьми*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8#185480) ([*грудями*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C)), [*кіньми*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C), [*слізьми*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0#115339), [*свиньми*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F#182683) ітд. Не дивно, що можна зустрїти і *річми*:

> <sub>Котляревський: [*Енеїда*](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE._%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC_1_(1922).djvu/181)</sub>
>
> 62. Юнона, козир молодиця,
>     Юпитеру не піддалась;
>     Бо знала, що стара лисиця
>     На всякі штуки удалась, —
>     Сказала: „о очей всіх світе,
>     „Старий Олимпський Єзуїте!
>     „З медовими *річми* сховайсь,
>     „Уже мене давно не любиш,
>     „А тільки пяний і голубиш…
>     „Одсунься геть  —  не підсипайсь.

---

> <sub>Авторка запитання</sub>
>
> На форумі натрапила на нічим не підкріплене правило про парні і непарні речі.

Усталений термін цего явища: [*двоїна*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%86%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA). Некоректно називати *парні*, бо *шїсть*, *вісїм* — теж *парні*, а *три* — *непарне*, але може бути частиною *двоїни*.

Гісторично, закінчення в згаданому випадку є *-ьма*, але оскільки шипячі частково ствердїли, то *ь* або замінюїть ся на *и*, або геть зникає, тому маємо *речима*. Також може бути *річма*, але вжиток не бачу, хоча подібне слово *нічма* — має і записано в словнику:

> <sub>Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні НАН України.</sub>
>
> [НІЧ](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87#10123)
>
> 9. ні́чма — «уночі»

Однак з часом з різних причин двоїна:

- зникла, досі [локально] існує або можливо якось ся видозмінила,
- замінила стару множину, наприклад *очі* проти [*ока*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/oko),
- ще одна форма множини, тобто як з *речима* і *речами* в загальній розмовній мові.

В підсумку, сучасний стандард української не фіксує двоїну, а деякі збережені форми записує ві винятки або в парабіжні.

---

> <sub>Авторка запитання</sub>
>
> Так само цікавить, чому *плечі* в орудному відмінку збереглися як *плечима*.

Слово входить в другу відміну і мішану ґрупу, бо відповідно середнего роду і на *-ч*. Гісторично в мякій ґрупі з основою на *-ŏ*.

> <sub>[Правопис 2019](//files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=127) → Ⅱ. Правопис відмінюваних закінчення → Іменник → Ⅱ відміна → Б. Множина</sub>
>
> #### § 92. Орудний відмінок
>
> В орудному відмінку множини іменники другої відміни мають закінчення **-ами**, **-ями**, **-ми**.
>
> 1. Закінчення **-ами** (у твердій та мішаній групах), **-ями** (у м’якій, зрідка в мішаній групах) мають іменники чол. і середн. роду: *берег**а́ми***, *працівник**а́ми***, *товариш**а́ми***, *трактор**а́ми***; *во́х**ами***, *міст**а́ми***, *прі́звищ**ами***, *се́л**ами***, *я́вищ**ами***; *ковал**я́ми***, *лікар**я́ми***, *шахтар**я́ми***; *знаря́дд**ями***, *місц**я́ми***, *обли́чч**ями***, *пол**я́ми***, *роздорі́жж**ями***, *узви́шш**ями***.
> 2. Закінчення **-ми** (паралельно з формами на -**ами**, **-ями**) мають іменники чол. і середн. роду: *гі́сть**ми*** (і *го́ст**я́ми***), *кі́нь**ми*** (і *ко́н**ями***), *чобіть**ми́*** (і *чобо́т**ями***, *чо́бот**ами***); *колі́нь**ми*** (і *колі́н**ами***), *колі́сь**ми*** (і *коле́с**ами***), *криль**ми́*** (і *кри́л**ами***).
>
> <sup>**Примітка**. Іменники середн. роду óко, плечé мають в орудному відмінку множини закінчення **-има**: *оч**и́ма***, *плеч**и́ма***.</sup>

Тобто згідно правил тут лише *плечима*. Тут, в другому пункту, можна побачити знайме нам *-ьми*, котре чомусь позначене як *-ми*, але без прикладу такого — умовно може появити ся після приголосних, котрі зараз завжди тверді чи мякі або частково ствердїли (шипячі і *р*), а ранїше мали *ь*. З [неточного] прикладу, бо тут іменник має лише множнину, пригадую хиба що [*дверми*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8), що від [*двьрь*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96#5068).

[Гісторично](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B7_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D0%BD%D0%B0_*-%C5%8F), тут закінчення звичне *-и* (по-сучасному *-і*) і двоїнна *-ема*, але через вплив гинших основ як *-ŭ*, *-ā* та знайма *-ĭ*, орудний набув сучасних форм: звичні різні *-ами*, *-ьми* і двоїнну *-ьма*. Подібне стало ся і зі згаданим словом [*колісьми*](/a/7031/585).

Тут двоїнна форма *плечі* повністю витїснила множину *плеча*.